# Malformed XML response with manual newline characters

Tags: node.js, xml, axios, get

I am using a GET request to fetch what I expect to be an XML document from an endpoint. The response has the following structure:

```
'  <itunes:explicit>clean</itunes:explicit>\n' +
'  <itunes:episode>11</itunes:episode>\n' +
'  <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>\n' +
```

(This is from a console log in a Node.js function).

I haven't encountered a response like this before and am having trouble doing anything useful with it. I've tried:

- Changing the response type and encoding of my GET function
- Parsing the response with an XML parser - this throws an error
- Removing the newline and + characters manually with regex (I'd like to avoid this, but it doesn't seem to work anyway)

It's worth saying that the response looks as you'd expect in a browser window:

[image]

Am I missing something fundamental about how this data is encoded / structured and what is the best way to turn it into something I can work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie error. In case anyone else stumbles across this; I expected the response from my Axios GET request to be the xml. The response was actually in a `data` property in the response:

```
const response = await axios.get(url);
const myXML = response.data;
```